# Bootstrap 5.1.3: 3rem in margin-top in row descendants

Tags: css, npm, sass, margin, bootstrap-5

I installed bootstrap 5.1.3 with npm in a project. I built a page with the tipical bootstrap classes, but every '.row > * ' has a margin-top: 3rem; and I don't know why, and how to avoid it. Where has my configure ruined?

My local app.scss is like this, I haven't import any local scss yet.

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
```

But in the compiled app.css the .row > * has a margin-top: 3rem, and I dont know why:

````
.row > * {
...
  margin-top: 3rem;
}```

Is this the normal behavior of bootstrap 5.1.3?
````

Comment: No, this isn't normal, it should be `margin-top: calc(-1 * var(--bs-gutter-y));`

Comment: @Simp4Code then what could go wrong to get this?